# Swift querying Parse all objects in class

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have an app that I need to grab all values in the class. I need to get "players" and "total" from the class "runningTotal". Here is the code I have:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"runningTotal")
    query.selectKeys(["players", "total"])
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
    {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil
        {
            self.test = objects[0]["total"]
        }
    }
```

I want to set a variable (test) equal to the result of total. I would also want to do this with players. I don't think the above code is right, as it doesn't work. I obviously don't need any constraints as I want to fetch all of the results from this class. How would I go about solving this?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific about why it doesn't work? Compilation error, runtime error, unexpected result, ...

Comment: Nothing is passed into the variable. (Ie. There is no result coming from parse)

Comment: Are you sure it's not returning an error? You're checking for `error == nil`, but doing nothing if there's an error. I suggest to set a breakpoint at that line and see what happens

Comment: I have already checked for an error and nothing is wrong. Is this the correct parse syntax to use to return all results from a table, unfiltered and without constraints?

Comment: The code looks correct. What's strange is that if there's actually no result, then it should crash at this line: `objects[0]["total"]`, because the array should be empty. Have you tried inspecting the content of `objects`?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in Xcode, open the debug area and in the left side of it you should have the list of all variables/properties in scope

Comment: An exception breakpoint?

Comment: http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

As long as your query is error free, you'll need to iterate through the `objects` array. As you iterate through each `object`, which will be of type `AnyObject`, you will need to cast the `object` as a `PFObject`. Then you will be able to grab the data you require from it.

```
   var query = PFQuery(className:"runningTotal")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil{
                for object in objects{
                    if let data = object as! PFObject{
                        //Set test to total (assuming self.test is Int)
                        self.test = data["total"] as! Int
                    }
                }
            }else{
                //Handle error
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got this error message, /Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/Controllers/Profile/DirectoryTableViewController.swift:38:15: Cannot invoke 'findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '(([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void)'